# .htaccess not being loaded in Ubuntu 14.04 (Apache 2.4.7)

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, .htaccess, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to use the `.htaccess` file in Ubuntu 14.04 (Apache 2.4.7).

Here is what my `.htaccess` looks like

```
# 1 YEAR
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|svg|woff|eot|ttf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 1 WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

# Add correct content-type for fonts 
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/x-woff .woff
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

# Compress compressible fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf font/otf image/svg+xml
```

I enabled mod_rewrite using `a2enmod rewrite`

Then I edited `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` as follows

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess
```

However the `.htaccess` file is still not being loaded. If I add gibberish to the `.htaccess` file everything still works fine. The `.htaccess` is located in `/var/www/`.

Here is the output of `apache2ctl -S`

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost edmhunters.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/edmhunters.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.edmhunters.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: If you have write access to the virtualhost config file, put the `.htaccess` content in there and set `AllowOverride` to `None`, as this removes the need for apache to scan the whole directory tree above each request for `.htaccess` files. Read: performance is negatively influenced by using `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score -1):

The isssue was that I was placing the `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/` while my `DocumentRoot` for my website was pointing to a different directory. Moving the `.htaccess` file to that folder solved the issue.